# Gem permission issues with rbenv running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

I am using Rbenv to manage my ruby versions, and don't remember ever having an issue before. It's been a while since I developed at home though.

Basically this is what happens:

```
➣ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
➣ rbenv local
2.3.1
➣ rbenv global
2.3.1
```

Really not sure what I'm missing. Never seen this issue before.

Comment: put `sudo` at the beggining of the command.

Comment: that doesn't really solve the problem. I'm using a versioning system for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rPat, what does the command

```
$ which gem
```

reveal? If it indicates you're using the the system gem command, try

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

and see if that resolves the issue.

Also make sure

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

is in your .bash_profile

Comment: $ which gem:

`/usr/bin/gem`

Comment: The proper output for that command would look something like "/Users/david/.rbenv/shims/gem"

Comment: Yup, you got me on the right path. Somehow my .bash_profile didn't have `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. Could be when I was messing with my command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the system version at the moment, and it sounds like you want to use a private Ruby.  First, make sure that you have the current `rbenv` version by following the [Upgrading](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#upgrading) instructions.

When you have the most recent version of `rbenv`, pick a version of Ruby that you want to use (e.g. 2.2.5) and run:

```
rbenv install 2.2.5
```

This will install that Ruby version privately.

Next, you can set the version to use, by default, run this to set the Ruby version as your local default:

```
rbenv local 2.2.5
```

And that should get you up and running.